# Pass Request on server in xml formate in android

Tags: android, soap, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have to request on server in form of an xml and get the response. Currently I am getting the xml not correct error. Don't know where it is wrong or my way is not correct. Below is my Xml and code I am trying.

**XML:**

```
<txn><ssl_merchant_id>893</ssl_merchant_id>
<ssl_user_id>page</ssl_user_id><ssl_pin>3472</ssl_pin>
<ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode><ssl_transaction_type>ccsale
</ssl_transaction_type><ssl_card_number>1234567890123456
</ssl_card_number><ssl_exp_date>1617</ssl_exp_date><ssl_amount>
</ssl_amount></txn>
```

Code I have tried:

```
try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://demo.myvirtualmerchant.com/VirtualMerchantDemo/processxml.do");

            try {
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<txn><ssl_merchant_id>893</ssl_merchant_id>"+
                        "<ssl_user_id>page</ssl_user_id><ssl_pin>3472</ssl_pin>"+
                        "<ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode><ssl_transaction_type>ccsale"+
                        "</ssl_transaction_type><ssl_card_number>1234567890123456"+
                        "</ssl_card_number><ssl_exp_date>1617</ssl_exp_date><ssl_amount>1.00"+
                        "</ssl_amount></txn>", HTTP.UTF_8);
                se.setContentType("text/xml");
                httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
                httppost.setEntity(se);

                HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
                Log.d("request", response_string);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The response which I got is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<txn><errorCode>6042</errorCode><errorName>Invalid Request Format</errorName><errorMessage>XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete.</errorMessage></txn>
```

Please suggest me something how to get rid off this issue. I heard about SOAP but don't know how to use that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your XML is what the server expects, I suggest trying to use [RequestMaker](http://www.requestmaker.com/) to see if the problem is really Android related. You can also modify encoding and HTTP header elements to test various options.

I think that your intention is to use SOAP for a Web service request, but your XML fragment is definitely not SOAP! Find here a step by step guide to calling a SOAP Web service: [LINK](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)